# combinations of an array of array members java ( dice roll? )

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, dice

really sorry for not writing where i am at,   as i have no clue how to start and had no luck searching.

for example if i have

```
int [][]={{1,2,3},              //possible states of 1 member
          {10,20,30},           //possible states of 2 member
          {100,200,300}}        //possible states of 3 member
```

I need to define k - number of combination member arrays, and then get the result in the way, that i get all possible combinations of their states. So basically if the k is 2:

```
member(1st array)1 - member2
member1 - member3 
member2 - member3
```

Then get combinations of all possible states of those members, that members cannot combine with each other.

You can imagine having 3 dices (in this case all 3 sided ) and i want to get all possible combinations i get get by throwing all possible pairs of dices (dice1 + dice2 is the same as dice2 + dice1, so i don't want that). I don't know how many dices i will have and how many sides i will have.

Any pointers, starting advice or anything is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: how about, select a member, match it with every side of every other dice (except for the ones with member index less than or equal to itself).

Comment: that should work, but i cannot wrap my head around it how to start a code:/, any example possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you can do something like this. Just a solution, not so great in time complexity.

```
    for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){  // Selects one dice
        for(int j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++){  // Select another dice
            for(int k=0; k<x[i].length; k++){  // selects face of first dice
                for(int l=0; l<x[j].length; l++){  // select face of 2nd dice
                    System.out.print("Dice " + i + " Face " + k + " vs Dice " + j + " Face " + l);
                    System.out.println(" ==> " + x[i][k]+ " - " + x[j][l]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As i need only k from 2 to 4, i can just add another for loops to select another dice and face and have simply in case k ... ? It would be interesting to see how it would look like with really variable k.

Comment: you can try that out.. also remember its not good to nest multiple loops as it will give very bad time complexity to your algorithm. Also pls vote/accept if it helped..